# how to create Date object from String value

Tags: java, date-format, simpledateformat, date-formatting

When running through the below code I am getting  an `UNPARSABLE DATE EXCEPTION`.

How do I fix this?

```
   package dateWork;

    import java.text.DateFormat;
    import java.text.ParseException;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Date;

    public class DateCreation {

        /**
         * @param args
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            String startDateString = "2013-03-26";
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd"); 
            Date startDate=null;
            String newDateString = null;
            try 
            {
                startDate = df.parse(startDateString);
                newDateString = df.format(startDate);
                System.out.println(startDate);
            } catch (ParseException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: hint you have 2 formats of date in there, but only one SimpleDateFormat

Comment: Try `-`:   `String startDateString = "2013-03-26";
  DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You used wrong dateformat for month, also you should use the same delimiter as in your date.

If you date string is of format `"2013/01/03"`

use the same delimiter `/` for the pattern `"yyyy/MM/dd"`

If your date string is of format `"2013-01-03"`

use the same delimiter '-' in your pattern `"yyyy-MM-dd"`

```
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd");
```

should be

```
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
```

From [**SimpleDateFormat Doc**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

MM---> month in an year

mm---> minutes in hour

Answer (score 1):

```
String startDateString = "2013-03-26";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
```

you are using different pattern than what you are parsing.

either initialize this as `DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");` 
or this as `String startDateString = "2013/03/26";`

[also look this article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 1):

`MM` instead of `mm`

`-` instead of `/`
ie `yyyy-MM-dd` as you are using `-` in date string

Answer (score 0):

pass same format string in constructor of SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd")

as your string date is "2013-03-26"

if your date is "2013/03/26" use

SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd")