# groovy/java regex check if "yyyy.MM.dd" format

Tags: java, regex, date, groovy

I have a string representing a date, for example `"2010.12.25"`. How can I control if it is of "yyyy.MM.dd" format? There is no need to check the validness of the date.

Comment: What do you mean by control? What exactly do you need?

Comment: use simple date format , refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15760248/how-to-create-date-object-from-string-value)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have the Regex, in Groovy, you can just do:

```
boolean match = "2010.12.12" ==~ /\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}/
```

Answer (score 5):

use `SimpleDateFormat` to `parse()` the string, handling the exception to decide if it is a valid date string.  don't use regex to check a date. e.g.:

```
2010.30.40
2010.13.34
```

Answer (score 3):

```
try {
    Date.parse('yyyy.MM.dd', '2013.12.21')
} catch(java.text.ParseException p) {
    println "Unparseable Date"
}
​
```

You can also use Groovy Date parsing to check the accuracy of date format.

Comment: Oddly it doesn't work always for e.g. if you entered the dates as 2016.01.99 it still parses it

Answer (score 1):

You can check the format of the date by using a [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) like this, because using `regex` for validating date formats is a very bad practice, IMHO.

```
String strDate = "2010.12.25";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd");
try {
    Date date = df.parse(strDate);
    // If it comes here, then its a valid format
} catch (ParseException pe) {
    // If it comes here, then its not a valid date of this format.
}
```

Comment: @NandkumarTekale - Please refer the docs. `mm` is for minutes and `MM` is for month.

Comment: can you elaborate why do you think using regex for validating date formats is a very bad practice ?

Comment: @Busted: Because that is not the purpose of regex. The date api along with the formats were created exactly for this purpose. There is no point in reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Try to this check this with method `isValid(String dateStr)`,

```
 boolean isValid(String dateStr) {
     Matcher matcher=
        Pattern.compile("\\d{4}\\.\\d{2}\\.\\d{2}").matcher(dateStr);
    return matcher.matches();
  }
```

Comment: `.` matches any character e.g. `1234567890` would match.

Comment: @Imagination, OP don't want the validness of Date.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
 String a = "2010.12.12";

            System.out.println(a.matches("\\d{4}\\.\\d{2}\\.\\d{2}"));
```

**Output** will be `true`

Comment: this won't `check the validness of the date.`

Comment: @Imagination from the Q: _"There is no need to check the validness of the date"_

Comment: It will validate this `1234.67K90`.