# How to check if a value displays in particular format in XML response in soapui

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am trying to use using script assertion or by groovy code to check if a value under an element in xml response exits in particular format.

Sample response :

```
                 <ns5:price>99.99</ns5:price>
                 <ns5:date>2016-04-04</ns5:date>
                 <ns5:quantity>1</ns5:quantity>
```

For example, I want to check if any price exists and in format `5,4`, same for date to see if date in format `yyyy-mm-dd` and quantity is not `0`.

All the values are dynamic.

I am wondering if we can use using a script assertion or can use point and click with soap ui pro.

I am just learning soapui pro and groovy.

Thanks.

Comment: Are these values repeating in the response?  You can use script assertion.

Comment: Check it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20143208/groovy-java-regex-check-if-yyyy-mm-dd-format) regarding date format

Answer (score 1):

You can create an *script assertion* in your *SOAP testStep* and make the validations there. In the *script assertion* you can parse the response using a [`XmlSlurper`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/XmlSlurper.html), then get the desired nodes using [`findAll`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/slurpersupport/GPathResult.html#findAll(groovy.lang.Closure)) and perform all the asserts. You can do it using something like:

```java
// from script assertion get the response 
def response = messageExchange.getResponseContent()
// parse the XML
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(response)
// get all prices
def prices = xml.'**'.findAll { it.name() == 'price' }
// check that each one has at "max 5 digits.max 4 digits"
prices.each { assert it ==~ /\d{0,5}\.\d{0,4}/ }
// get all dates
def date = xml.'**'.findAll { it.name() == 'date' }
// check the date has yyyy-MM-dd format
date.each { assert it  ==~ /\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}/ }
// get all quantities
def quantity = xml.'**'.findAll { it.name() == 'quantity' }
// check that all quantities are > 0
quantity.each { assert it.text().toInteger() > 0 }
```

**NOTE:** To add an *script assertion* to your request, click on *Assertions* tab on left down corner of your *SOAP Request* panel:

[image]

Then right click on it and select *add Assertion*:

[image]

In a new panel select *Script* from a left side menu and then *Script Assertion* on the right options:

[image]

Finally use the code provided and make your checks `:)`:

[image]

Comment: @user6221615 nice to help you, if the answer helps you think about [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) `:)`