# String to Date 24 Hour Format Java

Tags: java, string, date, format

I have a String in the Format `dd.MM.yy HH:mm` e.g. `12.04.14 07:00`.
I convert that String into a Date object with the lines:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdfToDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy HH:mm");
Date date_new = sdfToDate.parse(date);
```

But then the Date is in the following Format:

> Apr 12, 2014 7:00:00 AM

**I need to display 24h Time. How I can do that?**

Comment: check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842245/converting-date-time-to-24-hour-format

Comment: That is about a String and not about a Date object.

Comment: again format the resultant string using new format. i have added below

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
String dateStr = "Apr 12, 2014 7:00:00 AM";
DateFormat readFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss aa");
DateFormat writeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = null;
try
{
    date = readFormat.parse( dateStr );
}
catch ( ParseException e )
{
        e.printStackTrace();
}
if( date != null )
{
    String formattedDate = writeFormat.format( date );
}
```

Comment: I need a Date object not a String.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15760248/how-to-create-date-object-from-string-value

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way:

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy HH:mm").parse("12.04.14 07:00");
String formated = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy HH:mm:ss").format(date);
System.out.println(formated);
```

OUTPUT:

```
12.04.14 07:00:00
```

Comment: I need a Date object not a String.

Comment: The Date object you already get in the first line. And if you call the `toString()` method, do not wonder but read the Javadoc, which states: _Converts this `Date` object to a `String` of the form: dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy_

Comment: Yes. But I don't call the method toString(). I want to use this date object in a JSON Array, but I need 24h time.

Comment: Could you add the code where you convert the date to JSON to your question? How should one know? The question is not even tagged with JSON.

Comment: You can't know. But I thought it is not necessary. When I call System.out.println(date) it should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
String formattedDate=null;
String dateStr = "Jul 27, 2011 8:35:29 PM";
DateFormat readFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss aa");
DateFormat writeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = null;
try
{
    date = readFormat.parse( dateStr );

}
catch ( ParseException e )
{
        e.printStackTrace();
}
if( date != null )
{
    formattedDate = writeFormat.format( date );

}
try
{
    Date format=writeFormat.parse(formattedDate);

}
catch ( ParseException e )
{
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If you want as a date object again convert using format method. final date object

> Date format=writeFormat.parse(formattedDate);

Comment: I'll still get that as Output: Jul 27, 2011 8:35:00 PM

Comment: i am getting Wed Jul 27 20:35:29 PDT 2011 for System.out.println(format.toString());

Comment: That is again a String.

Answer (score 0):

use this code that will give you output in 24 hour format

```
Date d = new Date();
String dd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd k:mm:ss").format(d);
```

output will be

> 2014-04-11 18:20:55